# Как перемещать объекты с одного listbox на другой и обратно через ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, listbox

У меня есть список разных наименований телефонов: одна таблица (неактивные), вторая таблица (активные) и две кнопки между ними: добавить (перенос слева направо) и удалить (перенос справа налево). Когда выбираю объект в левой таблице и нажимаю кнопку добавить объект исчезает, удаляется объект из коллекции и добавляется в коллекцию (активных), но в правой таблице не происходит обновления, хотя дебаг говорит, что коллекция получила объект. Говорят, что это связано с биндингом, что вторую таблицу просто игнорирует. Можете помочь решить проблему?

```
class Phone : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private List<string> _title;
private List<string> _ActiveTitle;

public string SelectedTitle
    {
        get { return _selectedTitle; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTitle != value)
                _selectedTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTitle");
        }
    }

public List<string> Title
{
    get
    { 
         if (_title == null)
             _title = new List<string>();
         return _title;
    }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Title");
    }
}

public List<string> ActiveTitle
{
    get 
    { 
         if (_ActiveTitle == null)
             _ActiveTitle = new List<string>();
         return _ActiveTitle;
    }
    set
    {
        _ActiveTitle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ActiveTitle");
    }
}

public ICommand AddTitle
    {
        get { return _addTitle ?? (_addTitle = new RelayCommand(OnAddTitle)); }
    }

private void OnAddTitle()
    {
        if (SelectedTitle == null)
            return;

            ActiveTitle.Add(SelectedTitle);
            Title.Remove(SelectedTitle);
            OnRefresh();
    }

private void OnRefresh() 
{
     OnPropertyChanged("ActiveTitle");
     OnPropertyChanged("Title");
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _title;
private ObservableCollection<string> _ActiveTitle;
```

Именно этот класс коллекций уведомляет пользовательский интерфейс о изменении количества элементов и заставляет его (интерфейс) перерисоваться. И тип свойств тоже поменять не забудьте.

Comment: сейчас проверю.

Comment: работать не будет. Во-первых, не свойство, во-вторых не публичное

Comment: Как видите, автор пометил что работает :) Будет работать, если как я написал, и тип свойств поменять. А без замены типа свойств не будет компилироваться.